# Background image not displaying on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I can see the background image on my laptop but on mobile devices I cant see the background?

Please help.

```
#header {
     background: url('../img/spoon.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please, could you share more information? Like the `#header` markup, what's the OS and browser of the devices? Is this a website? Is it externally hosted or are you working on localhost?

Comment: Please take the time to make sure your code samples are formatted properly.  You were completely missing a closing bracket.  How do we not know that your code is missing the same thing and that's why it isn't working?  Also please always provide a working fiddle or screenshots.

Comment: you can visit the test site http://www.rosettafaris.com/ until i setup jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sm31live/r2vpoj0h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with:

```
/* This image will be displayed fullscreen */
background:url('../img/spoon.jpg') no-repeat center center;
min-height:100%;
background-size:cover;
}

body{
/* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your issue on ios Safari
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) is a link to the Safari Web Content Guide. Scroll down to the Known iOS Resource limits and see if you fall under any of those categories!

Answer (score 0):

```
#header{
  background: url("../assets/lotus.png") no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Use background-size 100% 100% to adjust full screen width height in mobile